# How to reject an answer to maximum value of quadratic function?

Tags: functions, quadratics

The quadratic function $f(x)=-x^2+3kx-2k^2+1$ has a maximum value of $(h^2-k)$, where $h$ and $k$ are constants.

By completing the square, I have found the maximum value of $f(x)$ in terms of $k$, that is $\frac{k^2}{4}+1$, which is correct.

However, the question requires me to show that $k=2h-2$, which I can, but I got another answer as well and am unsure why there are two answers. My working is as follows:

After completing the square, $f(x)=-(x-\frac{3}{2}k)^2+\frac{k^2}{4}+1$

When $x=\frac{3}{2}k$, maximum value $=h^2-k$

By equating the maximum value, $h^2-k=\frac{k^2}{4}+1$

$4h^2-4k=k^2+4$

$k^2+4k+4-4h^2=0$

$[k+(2+2h)][k+(2-2h)]=0$

Solving the equation, I get 2 answers:

$k+(2+2h)=0$

> $k=-2h-2$

and

$k+(2-2h)=0$

> $k=2h-2$ (shown)

Since substituting both answers satisfies the two expressions of the maximum value $h^2-k$ and $\frac{k^2}{4}+1$, may I know why and how to reject $k=-2h-2$, and why $k=2h-2$ is accepted?

Comment: Both are valid.  Asking you to prove that $k=2h-2$ is not correct.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't left any info out of the question? For $k = -2h - 2$ (linear equation), as $h$ increases, $k$ decreases, which would mean $h^2 - k$ would also increase. With $k = 2h - 2$, as $h$ increases, $k$ also increases and $h^2  - k$ won't increase or increases at a slower rate than compared to $k = -2h - 2$

Comment: @AgentSmith Thank you for pointing this out. No, I have not left any info out of the question. I believe the question has been simplified for a lower level without considering the possible solutions.

Comment: @gc3941d, we could come up with a *constraint* to reject $k = -2h - 2$ as a solution i.e. make it an *extraneous solution*. For $h > 1$, $-2h - 2 < 0$

Comment: For any given values of $h$ and $k$, $h^2 - k$ for $-2h -2$ is $h^2 + 2h + 2$ and $h^2 -k$ for $2h - 2$ is $h^2 - 2h + 2$. $h^2 + 2h + 2 > h^2 - 2h + 2$. The same goes for $\frac{k^2}{4} + 1$

Comment: Is there a *definition* for $h$? I.e. that it is not just some random parameter that you are expected to find for no particular reason. It is possible that definition is sufficient to rule out the other solution.